# how to make glowroot not to capture queries with bind parameters?

Tags: glowroot

By default my glowroot is capturing all the bind parameters and not aggregating the queries. How can I aggregate the queries without bind parameters. All I need is total count etc of similar query with ?  in place of parameters, but it is listing all the instances of similar query with parameters by default. Please help me in fixing this?

I have tried by having * in "do not capture bind parameter for these queries" option of jdbc plugin of glowroot, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

We achived this behavior by removing dot and asteriks (.*) on the jdbc configuration (*Capture bind parameters for these queries* config) as seen below.

[JDBC Queries in the Trace within the Transaction are visible, and the parameters field shows data before removing (.*) bind default parameters config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX9FI.png)

[JDBC Queries in the Trace within the Transaction are visible, but the parameters field appears empty after removing (.*) bind default parameters config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScFqI.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).